# RewriteCond match for certain Query param/value pair

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to do a redirect to another host if a certain parameter/value pair is in the querystring.

So far I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [&\?]abc=23&?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherserver.com/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

that works for:

```
/index.php?id=95&abc=23
/index.php?abc=23&id=95
/index.php?id=95&abc=23&bla=123
```

but it also matches `/index.php?id=95&abc=234` for example.

I need a pattern that matches exactly `abc=23`, no matter where it occurs.

Any suggestions on this? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd try this regex `(&|^)abc=23(&|$)` and match is only against `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

Answer (score 1):

[The question mark makes the preceding token in the regular expression optional. E.g.: colou?r matches colour or color.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [&\?]abc=23&?
```

You are matching abc=23& OR abc=23 with the rest of the string unconstrained so abc=234 is a valid match.  What you really want is & or nothing else.  I'm not sure if this RegExp is legal in Apache but it would be written as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [&\?]abc=23(&|$)
```

Here are the test cases I used at my [favourite online RegExp tester](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/):

```
abc=23&def=123
abc=234
abc=23
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that the question mark makes the preceding token optional. I did add it because otherwise it would not have matched index.php?id=95&abc=23 (it would only match if there were a "&" after 23)

Comment: Oh I see Lukas already wrote that.  Hmm, need to type faster.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to escape `?` within a character class. `[&?]` is perfectly valid, and matches an ampersand or a question mark.