# RewriteCond match for certain parameter values, part 2

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Before I begin, let me just say that I know my question is *almost* identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542488/rewritecond-match-for-certain-query-param-value-pair).

The difference is that, while I am trying to use a RewriteCond to identify a specific parameter in the query and redirect appropriately, I *do not* want the query string appended to the resulting URL.

Here's what I'm trying to do in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} d=i1013
RewriteRule subpages/view.php http://www.newdomain.com/
```

Except when I go to www.example.com/subpages/view.php?d=i1013, it redirects to www.newdomain.com/?d=i1013 and I want it to redirect to just www.newdomain.com

What am I missing here? I thought that the query string would be appended if I typed www.bing.com/$1, but I'm not, I'm leaving it off. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "http://www.newdomain.com/?" without the qsappend flag (which is the default).  The empty query string replaces the original.

```
RewriteRule subpages/view.php http://www.newdomain.com/?
```

(And ServerFault seems a better place to ask this question, but don't do anything yourself at this point, it should soon enough be migrated there.)